# function chaining in ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I ran my program in dev everything works fine, I then migrate to test and I get null reference errors. I think this is due to the way javascript works and that I need to chain my functions. At the moment I have 3 functions onAfterRendering.

`this.loadModels();
this.setInitModels();
this.setContentParams();`

the error is coming in the last function. I'm trying to work out how to do load models function then on completition do setInitModels and then when that complete do setContentParams, will putting it at the bottom of that function fix this or do I need to chain it another way.

Comment: What is the error in console debugger?

Comment: Is there some asynchronous stuff happening? If yes, you should put your follow-up functions some kind of success callback. For example a `JSONModel` has the method `attachRequestCompleted`, which takes a function that will be called once the event is triggered. This function can then call your follow-up functions.

Answer (score 0):

Marc's hint is important and right. Without knowing what's actually going on inside your functions it's hard to give the right answer. Another way would be to use promises, something that Is easy to understand and to maintain.